# Number of arguments used by vprintf

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a wrapper around **printf** function:

```
enum Color {
    Black, White
};

void my_printf(char *fmt, ...)
{
    char big_buffer[1024];
    /* do some stuff */

    va_list myargs;
    va_start(myargs, fmt);
    int ret = vsprintf(big_buffer, fmt, myargs);

    /* process arguments that were not processed by vprintf */

    va_end(myargs);

}

/* example of usage */
my_printf("%d %ld %y %y\n", 3, 3L, Black, White); /* %y - knows how to printf colors */
```

**fmt** can contain standard **printf** specifiers and my custom specifiers. In **fmt** string custom specifiers are always located after standard specifiers. To process standard specifiers I use vprintf and then I process arguments that were not processed by **vprintf**. At the moment to do that I have to parse **fmt** string manually and do multiple **va_arg** depending on specifiers in **fmt** but it is error prone. Is it possible to use some function that will do appropriate multiple **va_arg** for me?

I tried to use **myargs** after **vprintf**. It seems to work. But as I understand it is illegal to use **va_list** objects after they were passed to other functions that may use **va_arg**.

**Note**: I know that in this particular case I can convert **color** to string before calling **my_printf** and use **%s** specifier in **fmt** instead of **%y**. It is just a simplified example. So the idea is that I have my custom specifiers and I have to process them inside **my_printf**. So no need propose answers that I shouldn't use custom specifiers.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show how you call `my_printf`, what it outputs, and what you want to process that `vprintf` does not.

Comment: Instead of posting the MCVE you have shifted the question.

Comment: why to you put twice `va_end(myargs);` ?

Comment: It is an error. Thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use some function that will do appropriate multiple va_arg for me?

No, there is no standard function that will do appropriate multiple `va_arg`.  If `vsprintf(big_buffer, fmt, myargs);` encounters invalid print specifiers, the result is *undefined behavior*. (UB).

> At the moment to do that I have to parse `fmt` string manually and do multiple `va_arg` depending on specifiers in `fmt` but it is error prone

This is what you have to do.

---

Consider posting a question with code that you used to parse `fmt` string manually and we could help make it less error prone.

---

Alternative: Code could invoke a different `print(...)` approach, negating the need for explicitly coded type specifiers.  [Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)

Comment: Thanks for link. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about downloading and use the [GNU implementation of printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)? It includes a *(relatively)* easy way to [customize printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) just as you showed us in your example.

Comment: I will consider it. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome-looking facility.  I should have known GNU printf would have something like that.  Thanks for the tip; good to know about.